Angular Language server crashes when working on an `nx` project with `nx serve`
The Angular language server in nvim crashes after each automatic rebuild/reload of nx serve. It crashes with Program does not contain "<PROJECT_PATH>/apps/org/src/app/app.component.ngtypecheck.ts"
I can reproduce this in a clean nx repository setup using npx create-nx-workspace@latest. I've selected angular and integrated monorepo in the setup dialog.
Then I start the dev-server using nx serve projectname.
When I edit any *.component.html file and save it, I get this message most of the times: notify.warn Client angularls quit with exit code 1 and signal 0. Check log for errors: C:\Users\lut\AppData\Local\nvim-data/lsp.log
Inside lsp.log, there's this error message: Program does not contain "c:/Users/myuser/IdeaProjects/projects/test/org/apps/org/src/app/app.component.ngtypecheck.ts"
Environment

Windows (!!) 10 22H2
Neovim v0.10.0
LazyVim V12.19.1 with the angular extra enabled
@angular/language-server@18.0.0
Angular 18.0.5
NX v19.3.1
mason.nvim at 0950b15
mason-lspconfig.nvim at 37a336b
nvim-lspconfig at 9c9eb07

I aso configured lspconfig to use root_dir as per this question
return {
angularls = {
  root_dir = require("lspconfig.util").root_pattern(".git"),
},

I've also filed an issue at the angular LSP repo, but it was considered out of scope, because the issue is not reproducible in VS Code, only in nvim.

Any hint on where to file the issue would also be helpful, if there is no direct answer on how to fix it. Also would be greatful to know if anyone else can reproduce it.

This place is not an issue tracker.

@romainl I came here from https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2Clsp&projects=&template=lsp_bug_report.yml
Where it says: "Why isn't X language server/feature working?" belong on stackoverflow

See also How to debug my vimrc for advice on trimming the Vim side into a minimal example.
